# Is there a command-line option to rename dotoutput file when executing jdeps for multiple JARs of the same name?

Tags: java, unix, jdeps

I use below command to run jdeps in the whole directory. But it seems to be overwriting dotoutput files if there is multiple JARs of the same name.

```
find . -name '*.jar' -exec jdeps -dotoutput . -jdkinternals {} \;
```